# Recursive way of display alphabet in c

Tags: c

I am quite newbie in c, so I just starting off with some code, experimenting some stuff, right now I am stuck with this problem  in C, creating a function that displays the alphabet in lowercase, on a single line, by ascending order, starting from the letter ’a’.

**This is where I am stuck:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int alfabet(unsigned int i) {    
   if(i <= 122) {
       char litera = i;
       return litera;
   }
   return alfabet(i+1);
}

int main() {
    int i = 97;
    printf(alfabet(i));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about adding a call to `printf` in alfabet?

Comment: Instead of using `97` and `122`, it would be clearer to use `'a'` and `'z'`

Comment: I don't see any characters/letters. Only integers. Don't use magic numbers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, you won't print anything really interesting. In fact, your application will crash because `printf()` require at least a `char *` parameter (a string).

Your `alfabet()` function seems not so bad, but you should print the letter in it :

```
int alfabet(unsigned int i) 
{

    if (i > 'z') {
        // Here is the stop condition. 
        // If the value is higher than 122 ('z' character), we stop recursivity)
        return; 
    }

    printf("%c ", i);

    // Otherwise, let's call this function with another character
    return alfabet(i+1);
}
```

Comment: Could replace 122 with 'z' perhaps

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Target simplicity

```
void alfabet(int c) {
   printf("%c", c);
   if (c < 'z') alfabet(c+1);
}
```

called from *main* as

```
alfabet('a');
```

You may add a `printf("\n");`

- the function prints the character given as parameter
- you only call recursively the function with the next character to be printed if necessary, i.e. if the current character is below *z*.

Comment: In what way is this different from the other answers?

Comment: Do only what's necessary. Only 1 (implicit) *return* for instance. I see there is another close answer - but it was in error at the time I wrote mine.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void alfabet(char i) {
   if(i < 'z')
   {
       alfabet(i+1);
   }
   printf("%c", i);
}

int  main() {
   char i = 'a';
   alfabet(i);
   return 0;
}
```

to print zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba. Or:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void alfabet(char i) {
   printf("%c", i);
   if(i < 'z')
   {
       alfabet(i+1);
   }
}

int  main() {
   char i = 'a';
   alfabet(i);
   return 0;
}
```

to print abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

Comment: You have got an error here, your program doesn't work as expected, the alphabet should be displayed starting from letter 'a'. To create the expected behavior, you should not do the recursive call before the printing

Comment: I was unsure of the meaning of "ascending order" in this context ;)

Answer (score 1):

As you are new in this language, the basic thing to know is that each and every character on the keyboard has its own ASCII value ranging from 000 to 127 (i.e. total 128).

Now if you want to print a to z in a single line, the ASCII value for 'a' is 97 and that for 'z' is 122.

So, for printing this on screen you need to learn the basic ***for loop*** structure.The syntax for basic for loop is as follows :-

```
for(expr1;expr2;expr3)
{
    Body of the loop;
}
```

Here, ***expr1*** refers to the ***initial value*** of the variable, ***expr2*** refers to the ***exit condition*** of the loop and ***expr3*** refers to the ***increment*** or ***decrement value***.

So, the code to print a to z is as follows :-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    print_alpha();
    getch();
}
void print_alpha()
{
    int i;
    for(i=97;i<+122;i++)
    {
       printf("%c",i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int  main() {
    int i = 97;
    printf("%c",alfabet(i));
    return 0;
}
```

You Have to provide format specifier in printf (i.e. %c for character, %d for integer) Just check `man printf` in terminal.

And **for printing a to z** you can use for loop suggested by @Michel Jord, for printing in one line just put space in place of `\n`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void print_alphabets(char i) {
  if(i>='a' && i<='z')
  {
    print_alphabets(i+1);
    printf("%c ", i);
  }
}

int main() { 
  char i;
  scanf("%c",&i);
  print_alphabets (i);

  return 0;
}
```